# Does Google Play Signing SHA256 fingerprint change after publishing once?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-signing

Use case: Using the `SHA256` fingerprint of the signed APK to encrypt some data and saving it to a file, and then decrypting in the app afterwards on release build. The data will have to be encrypted in a hard-coded way as we will use the keystore information and the one with Google Play Signing.

Edit: I'm asking this in a way where we don't explicitly update a new certificate after losing our keystore file, for example. This is only for the info about Google Play itself, whether they change it or not on their own.

I couldn't really find any documents about it (or maybe I don't know how to search) but as you know, when publishing an app, you can either enroll with Google Play Signing, or publish it normally. In our applications, we query the SHA256 fingerprint of the APK by using `PackageManager` to encrypt some info, and I know that using Google Play Signing changes the output for this, as we've encountered issues before.

The output change is roughly fine, as long as it is permanent and not changed. But, I'm not sure if that's the case, so here is my question:

Does Google Play App Signing change fingerprint or certificate on its own after it's been published once? Or does it keep the fingerprints or certificates same? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Every app either for debug or build has its own unique SHA key generated that uniquely identifies the app version.

> Does Google Play App Signing change fingerprint or certificate on its
> own after it's been published once? Or does it keep the fingerprints
> or certificates same?

No the Google console doesn't change the SHA key once it is assigned to the apk. As well from then everytime you publish an update for your app, this updated app version is linked as the subsequent child version of the parent release signed apk.

Comment: Okay, it's good to know that the signed APK's fingerprint will not change. What about after an update? I didn't ask this on my question so I'm sorry by the way.

Comment: After the update as u might know as well that we are required to change the version no. of our apk as well. That way the same SHA key is maintained but since now we hv updated the version no. it treats that update apk as the child of the parent apk and so thus u might hv noticed that the update takes much less time to be live compared to the first time. Because with the SHA key already generated it has all the info of app in advance encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

For one of my applications, I had to generate an application hash for OTP.
My Google Play app had a different hash than the one locally generated when signing with release.keystores. Then I used depyloyment.cert instead of release.keystores. I use release.keystores only for publish to Google Play.